# wkhtmltopdf reported an error: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-wkhtmltopdf

good day,  please im having this error when i click Export to pdf button…………………

‘’’
views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_rev                       alidate=True, no_store=True)

def exportToPdf(request, pk):
c = get_object_or_404(candidate, id=pk)
cookies = request.COOKIES
options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'cookie' : [
        ('csrftoken', cookies          ['csrftoken']),
        ('sessionid', cookies ['sessionid'])
    ]
}
pdf =   pdfkit.from_url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/'+str(c.id), False, options = options)
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=candidate.pdf'
return response
```

urls.py

path('int:pk/exporttopdf/',      views.exportToPdf, name='exporttopdf'),
‘’’